# Swift 3 : Setting a view by iterating through an array of views

Tags: ios, arrays, uiview, swift3

I have four UIView objects that are initially optionals. Then when I load the view they are put into an array and in a for loop each one of them is assigned a UIStackView. But when I check to see if global instance of the object is equal to one in the array, it is not. I'm really confused now.

```
//global

@IBOutlet weak var buttonA: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonB: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonC: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonD: UIButton!
var answerAView: UIView?
var answerBView: UIView?
var answerCView: UIView?
var answerDView: UIView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    var answersViews = [self.answerAView, self.answerBView, self.answerCView, self.answerDView]
    var buttons = [buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD]
    var answers = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    var count = 0
    for a in answers {
        let newStack = UIStackView()
        newStack.axis = .vertical
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.text = a
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        newStack.addArrangedSubview(label)

        newStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        newStack.spacing = 10
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttons[count], attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: rows[count], attribute:.width, multiplier: 0.15, constant:0.0).isActive = true
        answersViews[count] = newStack
        if answerAView == answersViews[count] {
            print("Settkekasldfjkskdjblvkjbalkvbksjbvb")//this does not print  
        }
        count += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: seems your code has few bugs in syntax wise...pls post full source..it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

May be you should write as below

```
//global
    var answerAView: UIView?
    var answerBView: UIView?
    var answerCView: UIView?
    var answerDView: UIView?

    //inside viewDidLoad
    var answersViews = [answerAView, answerBView, answerCView, answerDView]

    for view in answersViews {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.addSubview(view)
        print("success")
    }
```

Comment: I updated the code, as you can see I need the uiview to become a stack view

Comment: the code you write "answersViews[count] = newStack
" is wrong

Comment: why does it work when I use  @IBOutlet weak var answerA: UITextView!? as in answerAview = answerA.